# Multiple CSS Files

Tags: html, wordpress, css

So here's my idea..

Idea: Create multiple css files (which will be included via options in admin wordpress) for multi-color theme.  I already know how to load via options and statements.

I'm starting the theme development now, and running into a small problem.

Main style holds all all of the hard template information, that will not be changed via the color templates.

I have a secondary folder /css/ for the color changing css

I have both of them loading, and I clicked and viewed the source, so they are loading correctly.

Main:

```
/* Header Information
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
    width: 990px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
}
```

/css/peridot.css:

```
#header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E200;
}
```

But for some reason, the border will not appear.  I tried adding a background to see if that would appear, and it would not.  So what is the problem here?

---Edit---

[image]

This image shows my peridot.css , and shows element inspector in FireFox.

Comment: So what does your DOM inspector tell you?

Comment: please post some of your HTML so we can check your CSS against it

Comment: Yeah, check out the browser' element inspector - it'll tell you what exactly happens with those rules and whether they are overwritten

Comment: <div id="header">
  Header
 </div>

Inspector shows style.css, but not peridot (even though view source shows its loaded in the top)

Sorry I don't know what DOM is..

Comment: @ Down-Voter, may I ask why I was down voted.  I did look around the net for an answer before I asked on SO.  I am familiar with programming and markup languages, there is no reason I should have been down voted.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer, when viewing again in the 'View Source', I noticed that my media was set to '1' instead of screen 'screen' or 'all'.  I did this by messing up when I did my wp_enqueue_style and having the ,true) after the version number.. Simply removing the 'true' put the media to media="all" and now it works.

Thanks for the quick responses everyone.